# AWS log Insigts parse NGINX log

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to use aws log insights to run query on my log group that contains nginx log.

This is my log format that I have setup on my ec2 machine:

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

Sample NGINX Log:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [10/Nov/2020:15:28:30 +0530] "POST /xx HTTP/1.1" 200 57 "https://xxxx.in/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I am trying to parse this using log insights with the following code:

```
parse @message '* - - [*] "* * *" * * "-" "*"' as remote_addr, timestamp, request_type, location, protocol, response_code, body_bytes_sent
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Expression is invalid: parse@message'* - - [*] "* * *" * * "-" "*"'asremote_addr,timestamp,request_type,location,protocol,response_code,body_bytes_sent
```

Any help would be appreiciated

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're 99% of the way there. All that is missing is matching the number of selectors and output variables, so if you would append `user_agent` to your list it would start to work.

Sample working query:

```
fields @message
| parse @message '* - - [*] "* * *" * * "-" "*"' as remote_addr, timestamp, request_type, location, protocol, response_code, body_bytes_sent, user_agent
| display request_type, location
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be even better with referrer and user_agent

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| parse @message '* - - [*] "* * *" * * "*" "*"' as remote_addr, timestamp, request_type, location, protocol, response_code, body_bytes_sent, referrer, user_agent
| display @timestamp, remote_addr, request_type, location, protocol, response_code, body_bytes_sent, referrer, user_agent
| sort @timestamp desc
```